# SQL query to select rows where a column contains only specific values

Tags: sql

I have a table identities that looks like this.

```
id  child   order_in_child
 1   200        34
 1   700        11
 2   200        31
 2   200        74
 3   200        35
 3   400        19
```

I want to select the list of ids where all child are only 200.

```
id  
 2
```

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using aggregation, we can try:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM identities
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(child) = MAX(child) AND MIN(child) = 200;
```

The first condition of the `HAVING` clause asserts that a given `id` group of records has only a single `child` value.  The second condition asserts that this single value is 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
select DISTINCT id from identities where child = 200
```

Comment: But this would also include `id`s which have `child` values _other_ than 200.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No ! As we have used 'where' clause which filters data having child value equal to 200

Comment: From the OP: `I want to select the list of ids where all child are only 200.`

Comment: Yes. The query which I have written will work smoothly for this requirement