# SQL Query- To get a record specific to one particular value only

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table like below:

```
SID   GRADE
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       D
3       A
4       A
5       B
```

Now, I want only those records as an output wherein if a SID is only having grade as 'A', but no other grades-- those SIDs will be selected

Output will be:

```
SID     GRADE
3         A
4         A
```

I have already implemented this via below:

```
SELECT SID, MIN(GRADE)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SID
HAVING COUNT(GRADE) = 1
   AND MIN(GRADE) = 'A'
```

Just want to check if there is any other options available to achieve this output?

Comment: you can do nested query, use NOT IN (query to select SID where grade is not A), and put this in where

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: For A, `HAVING MAX(GRADE) = 'A'` also works. And also add MAX(GRADE) to the SELECT clause.

Comment: @jarlh yes, max Min both will work as along it is a distinct value.

Comment: MIN(GRADE) will return A even if there's a B too. If MAX(GRADE) returns A, there are no other values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to select rows where a column contains only specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708046/sql-query-to-select-rows-where-a-column-contains-only-specific-values)

Comment: @astenix- it also works

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `STRING_AGG` as an aggregation function. It's a little simpler as you save the count condition and it does also work for other grades (..which are not by chance at the beginning of the alphabet).

```
SELECT sid, string_agg(grade)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY sid
HAVING string_agg(grade) = 'A'
```

Comment: will try this option

Comment: That’s a neat way for testing for identical sets without working with set qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If inside one SID there is no way to have multiple A grades then below query will be enough

```sql
select a.SID from MYTABLE a 
where a.grade = 'A' 
  and not exists (select * from MYTABLE b where b.SID = a.SID and b.grade != 'A')
```

In case, when grade may be null condiftion should be slight different

```sql
select a.SID from MYTABLE a 
where a.grade = 'A' 
  and not exists (select * from MYTABLE b where b.SID = a.SID and (b.grade != 'A' or b.grade is null))
```

And full version - where there may be multiple A grades inside one SID and grade may be null

```sql
select DISTINCT a.SID from MYTABLE a 
where a.grade = 'A' 
  and not exists (select * from MYTABLE b where b.SID = a.SID and (b.grade != 'A' or b.grade is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT SID, 'A' AS GRADE
FROM (    
SELECT SID,
SUM(CASE WHEN GRADE <> 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LOGIC
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SID
)
WHERE LOGIC = 0
ORDER BY SID
```

Comment: My solution works for both distinct and non distinct values of A for a SID

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to return each SID which has `MAX(GRADE) = 'A'`, i.e. no other grades.

```
SELECT SID, MAX(GRADE)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SID
HAVING MAX(GRADE) = 'A'
```

**Edit:** If you instead want to search for another grade, that is not the minimum (or maximum), you can add a `MIN(GRADE)` condition to the `HAVING` clause. E.g.

```
SELECT SID, MAX(GRADE)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SID
HAVING MAX(GRADE) = 'B'
   AND MIN(GRADE) = 'B'
```

Will perform well on *most* databases. (However, Hana is unknown territory to me.)

Comment: Be careful, that this comes with the assumption that the grade in question is the lowest possible value.

Comment: But I believe, using this query, the SID 1&2 will also appear in the output, which I don't want

Comment: SID 1 is having max grade C, will not be returned. SID 2 is having max grade D, will not be returned.

Comment: @MathiasKemeter, yes, care has to be taken if changing the grading system. You can add `AND MIN(GRADE) = 'A'` to the HAVING clause - and perhaps still keep the performance. (I don't know the Hana optimizer, so I'm just guessing.)